# Unable to run Powershell script in DockerFile

Tags: docker, sitecore

I have an issue about unable to run Powershell script when building an image from Dockerfile, and still can't resolve it unless I remove the command.

Is there any way to  run the ps script in dockerfile?

Error：

> The container operating system does not match the host operating system

Here the full list of commands I tried: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zByLK.png

Host OS : Windows Server 2022 Datacenter (21H2)
Windows Docker Desktop 4.17.0
(using Windows Containers)

Comment: Whats the base image of the dockerfile?

Comment: @tkausl 
base image is "scr.sitecore.com/sxp/sitecore-xp1-cm:10.3-ltsc2019"

the Dockerfile as below
https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples/blob/develop/custom-images/docker-compose.xm1.override.yml